# getting the folder of a given file from a different file (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have subfolders for each of my commands and I'm wondering how I would check the name of the command's folder without having to add code into the command file itself. I've tried `folders.filter(folder => folder.includes(command)` and I'm hoping there's a similar way that could help me.

```js
const folders = fs.readdirSync(`./categories`);

for (const folder of folders) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(`./categories/${folder}`);
    for (const file of files) {
        const command = require(`./categories/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    };
};

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        const commandArgs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(command.category) // HERE - how would i check what subfolder the given command is in?
            .setTitle(command.name)
            .setDescription(command.description);
   }

   //code...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a property when retrieving it:

```js
const command = require(`./categories/${folder}/${file}`);
command.folder = folder;

client.commands.set(command.name, command);
```

Now you can use it when referencing the object:

```js
const commandArgs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("From folder: " + command.folder);
```

Comment: thank you so much i was trying to figure that out for like a day lmao